# what is uml stereotype and how to use it

Tags: class, inheritance, uml, modeling, stereotype

I'm drawing a class UML for a JAVA software design. I don't really understand what is a stereotype. The formal definition:

***The stereotype is a profile class which defines how an existing metaclass may be extended as part of a profile. It enables the use of a platform or domain specific terminology or notation in place of, or in addition to, the ones used for the extended metaclass***

Is that mean the stereotype should be the name of the parent class? But why there are some superclasses also has a stereotype?

So for example, I have a superclass Animal and a class dog which extends the Animal class, what could be the stereotype of both classes? Also, why there are some classes without stereotype.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### What is a stereotype and what are its purpose?

A stereotype extends UML by allowing **to categorize** some elements in a more detailed way than foreseen natively by UML. It helps to make the model more expressive.

A typical [example](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/%7Epearce/modules/lectures/ooa/analysis/ecb.htm) are the [Entity, Control, and Boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary) stereotypes.  They are used in a use-case driven design: in a class diagram, you can immediately find-out which classes represents the use-case logic (marked as `«control»` stereotype), which classes represents user-interface with actors (`«boundary»` stereotype), and which classes represents business/domain objects (marked as `«entity»`).

Another use of stereotypes is to indicate the way a class is supposed to be implemented, for [example](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/foreignKeyMapping.html) to mark as `«table»` classes that correspond to database tables that are related to in-memory objects, or to indicate among the objects which ones are `«persistent»`.  An even more common use is to show some concepts that are [language specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/visualstudio/modeling/standard-stereotypes-for-uml-models?view=vs-2015#NetProfile) and have no equivalent in UML.  I think in particular to C# `«struct»` which have a value semantic wheres C# classes have a reference semantic, or C# «property» (which is a stereotype at attribute level).

### How are stereotypes defined?

Sterotypes are defined in a [profile](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile-diagrams.html). You can see a [stereotype](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/stereotype.html) as a class in a profile diagram.

But it's not an ordinary class that you could relate to other classes in your model.  So there is no inheritance at play here.   You would never indicate a superclass as stereotype.

A stereotype is a class related to the "metamodel", which means the UML standard elements defined in the UML standard.  So it's a class of classes (or a class of associations, or of any other UML element).

To elaborate on your example, with an abstract superclass `Animal` and concrete sub-classes `Cat` and `Dog`:

- you could affect them all an `«entity»` profile, because they all belong to the domain model.
- if you would want to store the objects in an RDBMS using the [concrete table inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html),  you may use a stereotype «persistent»  for `Cat` and `Dog` (since concrete table inheritance pattern does not implement persistence for the abstract classes)